# Npm run dev / build command error when building vite react project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

The project worked just fine yesterday, now all of a sudden when using the npm run dev command in the terminal it gives me an error. I can't seem to find any fix for it too. I hope someone can help me.

failed to load config from C:...\vite.config.ts ReferenceError: plugin is not defined

I tried to update node, but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to give more information for us to help you, like what is the error? What changes have you made today? Did you try to undo it?

Comment: are you in the right directory?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your vite.config.ts file and carefully review its contents. Look for any references to a "plugin" that might be causing the issue. It's possible that there's a typo or a missing import.
- Check Dependencies:
  Ensure that you have all the necessary dependencies installed for your project. Run npm install or yarn install to make sure that your project's dependencies are up to date.
- Vite Version Compatibility:
  Make sure that your Vite version is compatible with the configuration and plugins you are using. Sometimes, upgrading or downgrading Vite might resolve such issues. You can check for the latest Vite updates by running npm outdated or yarn outdated.
  Clear Caches:
  Sometimes, caching issues can cause problems. Try clearing your npm or yarn cache by running: npm cache clean --force